# To generate md5sum for each value in a column (.CSV file) and then compare the generated md5sum value with the already given md5sum value

Tags: linux, bash, csv, unix, md5sum

I am a beginner with Linux and still learning and I am not able to proceed with a task

So there is a CSV file with few columns.

Column 1 - File name,

Column 2 - Path to the file,

Column 3 - md5sum values of that file( for each row).

My goal is to generate the md5sum value of the file ( column 1) by going to the path mentioned(column 2) and then compare the value with md5sum already present in the CSV file, all the while ignoring the first three rows ( headers). For all the rows in the CSV file

Example

```
cat Sample.csv

header1 
header2
file,pathTofile,md5sum
script.sh,/c/folder,987fg98df7g9df7g94353454
another.sh,/c/training/folder,54657981sdssgs654643535
```

**OUTPUT** ( *assuming* row 1 has the correct md5sum value and row 2 does not )

```
md5sum is a match for script.sh
md5sum is not a match for another.sh
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your md5 hashes are too short (24 and 23 characters instead of 32) and contain non-hex symbols (`...sg...`). Are these just placeholders for the actual 32-digit values?

Comment: Hi @Socowi yes they are just placeholder text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man md5sum`

> -c, --check
> read MD5 sums from the FILEs and check them

Here the FILE has the same format as `md5sum`'s output:

```
bb8c5900589a82f48e15c2688670de39  file1
f23d2d7f519425c547d9e4287940ef72  /path/to/file2
...
```

So you can re-arrange your csv file to have the same format and then run `md5sum -c`:

```
awk -F, 'NR>3 {print $3"  "$2"/"$1}' Sample.csv | md5sum -c
```

`NR>3` skips over your header. If your example isn't accurate, make sure to replace `3` with the actual number of header lines.

The output of `md5sum -c` looks like

```
file1: OK
/path/to/file2: OK
some/corrupted/file: FAILED
file4: OK
...
md5sum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
```

Comment: Hi @Socowi, thank you for this. I did not seem to think this way.
but this still has an issue, since the script would be required to generate the second md5sum value. Only once it is generated, this method can work by arranging them and then using `md5sum -c`

Comment: @Nikhil Sorry, I don't understand your comment and the described issue. What do you mean by *"`required to generate the second md5sum`*"? This sounds like you assume `md5sum -c` works like `diff`, comparing two lists of hashes, which is not the case. `md5sum -c` compares the old md5sums from your csv file with **md5sums computed on the fly** for each file. There is no 2nd csv file involved.

Comment: sorry I should have phrased it better.
I assume you meant to say that `md5sum -c`  will compare the $3 ( column 3 which is a md5sum value ) and `"$2"/"$1` ( column 2 and 1 concatenated, for which md5sum will be created on the fly? )
if that's the case how can I pass the input ,CSV file to 
`awk -F, 'NR>3 {print $3"  "$2"/"$1}' | md5sum -c`  since I am not sure how I can pass which file has to be read.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to add the file... Just put it as the last argument of `awk`. I edited the answer.

Comment: Even though I didn't get the required output, there is some progress. 
Goes onto show
`md5sum: /C/training: No such file or directory  
/c/training: Failed open or read  
md5sum: WARNING: 1 line is improperly formatted  
md5sum: WARNING: 2 listed files could not be read`  
Initially I thought there is something with the path I had mentioned, but that seems to be correct

Comment: I can only guess, because I neither have your original input file, not your file system. Could it be that your csv file has windows line endings? That would explain the `improperly formatted md5sum`. For the `No such file or directory` you should check the file system. Does `ls /c/training` work? `/c` is pretty strange for a Unix system.